# Nowdays farmers are _____________ mushrooms

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

> Nowdays farmers are _____________ mushrooms.

Options:

1. rising
2. grow
3. has raised
4. raising

My approach: I am confused between these two as I am not able to differentiate  after looking at their meaning.

> rising: going up, increasing, or sloping upward.
>
> raising: increase the amount, level, or strength of.

---

**Edit:**

Also I found the difference here. Is it correct?

Source:
http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/raise_rise_raze.htm

Comment: Well, the answer is 'growing'. "Nowadays farmers are growing mushrooms." But I see your questions are so basic, and you have so many mistakes in your posts. I would suggest you to post your questions on 'English Language Learners' website: http://ell.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @voyager I Edited the question.

Comment: Did you copy the options correctly? Because if I heard a farmer say he was raising mushrooms, carrots and strawberries I'd look at him very oddly. Where did you find these questions? Are they online? What's the title of the coursebook?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I wouldn't find "raising mushrooms" to be "odd".  In fact, the use of the term is almost literal, since the crop rises out of the ground (or manure pile, as the case may be).

Comment: @HotLicks   What about if you had to choose two between [cultivating / growing / raising / rearing mushrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungiculture)? Which two would you immediately discard?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'd discard "rearing".  The others are all legitimate uses, even if not equally popular.

Comment: I would prefer just leaving the gap empty. “Nowadays farmers are mushrooms”. Makes perfect sense. [Also note: the word is _nowadays_. There is no such word as _*nowdays_.]

Comment: Option 5. *cultivating*. (This needs a title edit: What's the difference between *rising* and *raising*?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "are" signals that a participle is required.  This will be the present participle ("-ing") to show the progressive tense for continuing action. So your choices are "rising" or "raising."

"Rise" means to go up.  It's intransitive (i.e., it cannot take an object, like "mushrooms"), so it won't do.

"Raise" is transitive and takes an object, telling us what was raised by the subject (here, farmers).  In the context of crops (or farm animals), "raise" means to tend or farm.  So "raising" fits the example.

("Raze" and "raise" are homophones, but in the context of buildings, they have opposite meaning.  If you **raise** a structure, you build it up; if you **raze** it, you tear it down.)

Answer (score 5):

Normally, the word 'raise' is associated with cattle. For crops (vegetables, grains, etc.) we use the word 'grow'. You can use the phrase 'raise mushrooms' but it sounds really awkward. 'Grow mushrooms' on the other hand is natural and suitable.

For a quick reference, see n-gram from Google showing usage of the two phrases. 
[image]

Comment: The problem is that "grow" doesn't fit the rest of the sentence, while "raising" does.

Comment: This might be a UK/US thing.  While "grow" may be more common, it's not at all unusual to hear "raise" used to refer to a crop, here in the US Midwest.  Do your Ngram for "corn" and "beets" and the numbers will be much closer (possibly because "grow mushrooms" is an idiom for unsanitary conditions).